# Ltrim,Trim functions not working for removing extra leading spaces in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a part of code:

```
If IsDate(cf1) Then
   cf1str = CStr(cf1)
   cf1str = Trim(cf1str)
   chk1 = Format(cf1, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")

   If cf1str <> chk1 Then
      MsgBox "message"
      Ws.Cells(i, c1).Select
      Selection.Activate
      Exit Sub
   End If
Else
   MsgBox ""
   Ws.Cells(i, c1).Select
   Selection.Activate
   Exit Sub
End If
```

What I want to do here is, I want to check whether the date is valid and is in the format "dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm-ss". Now as I am comparing the dates as strings, I want to make sure there is no mismatch due to leading or trailing spaces. I tried with `ltrim`, `trim`, `rtrim`, yet I find there are leading spaces in the column. As a result I get an error message saying date is not in correct format. This is creating a confusion among the code users as in what is the error, even if they see the date format is same in the cells. I tried to get rid of this by changing the strings into values by `Val()` function and then checking them, but in vain. Any solutions?

Also how to get rid of unwanted characters like `\n`, which `trim` may not eradicate? Because in one cell I see even the date is exactly in the order I want, without any spaces, still it's showing error message.

Comment: Why do you think `CStr` will give you format you want? `CStr(date)` is same as `Format(date, "general date")`.

Comment: A string comparison will only create confusions. Reason being see this example. If your cell has "    12/12/2012  00:00:00" and if you check for the format "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss" after trimming then it is not a match because of "/" and "-"

Comment: thanks for the reply.I know string comparisons will create such confusions as mentioned by you.But the purpose here is to keep the format strictly as "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss" , so that if any other format for the date comes up in any cell it will prompt the user to change it.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but the excel TRIM (application.worksheetfunctions.trim) and VBA trim are different functions with different results.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare strings. Compare dates. Try this:

```
If IsDate(cf1) Then
   cf1str = CStr(cf1)
   cf2 = CDate(chk1)

   If cf1 <> cf2 Then
      MsgBox "message"
      Ws.Cells(i, c1).Select
      Selection.Activate
      Exit Sub
   End If
Else
   MsgBox ""
   Ws.Cells(i, c1).Select
   Selection.Activate
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,my purpose is to check for the exact format of the date that i want,which is "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss" , for every data in the cell.Comparing dates will check whether the two dates are same, but wont serve my purpose

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it.
This is exactly what i wanted:

```
For Each cell In Selection.Cells
    If cell.HasFormula = False Then
        str = Trim(CStr(cell))
        If Len(str) > 0 Then
            nAscii = Asc(Left(str, 1))
            If nAscii < 33 Or nAscii = 160 Then
                If Len(str) > 1 Then
                    str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
                Else
                    str = ""
                End If
            End If
        End If
        cell=str
    End If
Next
```

This code checks for the first character in every string , and removes it if its not a simple space.Ascii characters less than 33 are all unseen characters behaving like white spaces and cannot be removed by trim or ltrim functions.This is the exact problem i was facing.ascii code 160 is for &nbsp in html,which often comes up in values,if directly pasted from html files,which was exactly my case.